# Predict photochemical decomposition of organic compound?

Tags: photochemistry

Is it possible to predict wether an organic compound will photochemically decompose?

Also, is it possible to predict the products which it will decompose into?

Answer (score 2):

Just as an experienced synthetic chemist can make an educated guess about how compound A and compound B will react, an experienced photochemist can usually do the same.  There are many, many well-known photochemical reactions that are mechanistically understood and sometimes even used in synthetic procedures, some commercially.  A few such reactions are the

Norrish Type I reaction

[image]

Norrish Type II reaction

[image]

Paterno-Buchi reaction

[image]

di-pi-methane reaction

[image]

photochemical induced halogenation, olefin dimerization and so many more.  So yes, an experienced photochemist can make reasonable predictions about which chemicals will react and what the possible products might be.